# Tracking internet activity of RDP sessions

Tags: rdp, terminal-services

Our product (Network Forensics and analytics tool) has a requirement to dissect RDP sessions on Windows 200x servers and

- Map each session to a logged-in account.
- Track all TCP/UDP sessions that are going to the internet.

  - URLs visited
  - External Servers and ports connected to, etc.

I have designed a code that can achieve this by installing an NT service on each of the terminal servers. This service will mine the data on that server and push it to my linux-based appliance. Alternatively it can log the information to the local Eventlog and then I can use simple WMI calls to retrieve this information.

However, I would like to know if there is a way to retrieve all TCP/UDP connections by polling the terminal servers externally (via WMI or otherwise) and gather the same information. Basically, I am trying to check if there is a way to avoid installing anything on the Windows terminal servers.

Thanks,

-Chandra